# How to add HiDPI resolution on High Sierra? Using standard scaled resolutions makes display blurry

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, resolution

**Main Question**: How to add 1024 x 640 HiDPI resolution on MacBook Air HighSierra internal display?

I'm trying to decrease resolution on my MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011, non-retina) Default resolution (1440x900) is clear and sharp but it makes fonts inside programs like Xcode and others too small, making it nearly impossible to read. So naturally, I wanted to increase the resolution as I did on windows (and older versions of MacOS). But in High Sierra, adjusting to other resolutions makes everything blurry.

I've downloaded RDM, a free tool that lets you set many resolutions (as opposed to the limited native Display Settings). The ones marked HiDPI in RDM all look crisp and perfect. The downside is, it doesn't have the resolution I'm looking for which is about: 1024 x 640 HiDPI. There is regular 1024 x 640 and it looks great size-wise but it's blurry. From HiDPI there are: 1280x800 (too small) and the next up is 960x600 (too big).

Other things I've tried:

- SwitchResX - just couldn't figure out how to add HiDPI resolution, only created regular ones (which are all blurry)
- Tried this web based generator, but also only was able to create non-HiDPI resolutions: https://comsysto.github.io/Display-Override-PropertyList-File-Parser-and-Generator-with-HiDPI-Support-For-Scaled-Resolutions/
- Spent several days reading about this but seems I'm missing a piece of the puzzle

Comment: In Xcode, for instance, did you tried to go to Xcode | Preferences | Fonts  and Colours and increase the font size for your theme? Other editing applications have also the possibility to select the font size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Yoan Those theme adjustments only affect the text inside the window where you type code, but the menus, resource lists menu items, everything is small to the point of being unusable. It's possible to see, but I'm sure it will adversely affect one's vision. I don't have a ruler handy otherwise I would take a photo for reference (screenshot probably wouldn't reflect what I'm seeing)

Comment: Maybe this page would be helpful: http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/23/increase-system-text-size-mac-os-x-scaled-resolution/ ?

Comment: Read that before. It just covers basic non-"hacking" techniques. I don't know why I need to "hack" something as basic as setting a screen resolution, but I guess that's just how Apple rolls. Original MacBook + original latest MacOS. Yet I can't do a simple change of resolution. Something that would take 10 seconds to change in Windows. I've read so much info these past few days about hex values of manufacturers etc. really hit the brick wall with this one. Hope some one can help out.